# Can I get facebook unique share count?

Tags: facebook, count, share

I can get the page's share (click) number in the link-stat table using FQL.
What I want to know is the unique share number, in other words can I get 
the number of users who share (group by Uid) the page.

Thanks in advance,

Onder

Comment: He Onder,

Did you already found the answer? I'm also looking for this...

Did you also mention that when a shared-item was deleted by a user the counter doesn't decrement?

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the link_stat table is user independent. The closest approximation would be to use the regular count

`SELECT share_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = A`